Identify the users platform with the c# dotnet SDK?
Because the official FFmpeg respository doesn't compile for Windows on ARM by default, I need to add a unofficial build into the project. For all other platforms it works automatically, therefore I only want to add the unofficial build, if the user is building for Windows on ARM.
I tried specifying it in the .csproj file the following way:
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(RuntimeIdentifier)' == 'win-arm64'"

    <Content Include="ffmpeg.exe">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory> 
    </Content> 

    <Content Include="ffprobe.exe">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory> 
    </Content> 

</ItemGroup>

With that attempt, the build works, but the files I want included do not get included. I attempted excluding every other platform with "!=" as well and if I do that, the files do get included, but on every platform, the excluding therefore does no work
If anybody could help me with that, that would be awesome

How do you build your image?

This file is part of a fork of Ryujinx: https://github.com/Otozinclus/Ryujinx-WinArm64
You build it using .net with the command "dotnet build -c Release -o [insert build folder name]"
When building, the files that get included will appear in the build folder that gets created


You build it using .net with the command "dotnet build -c Release -o [insert build folder name]"

You need to provide the RuntimeIdentifier for your build command:
dotnet build -c Release -r win-arm64 -o ...

see the dotnet build command reference

Thank you, that makes sense. Sadly this triggers an error when building "Building a solution with a specific Runtime identifier is not supported"

@Otozinclus are you building a library?

There might be some libraries included in Ryujinx. But sadly I don't know what is happening in most of the project, I just want to add FFmpeg for Windows ARM, without adding it for other platforms and don't really have the knowledge on much else

@Otozinclus can you please provide full repro steps? i.e. what branch, what project, what build command are you running?
